# Did the Avengers do the same in the comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, the Avengers

> went back in time to get the Stones and undo what Thanos did.

Is that what happened in the comics?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes (there's two now) are for lack of prior research, which is a valid downvote reason here on StackExchange. As OrangeDog's answer indicates, a cursory search on Wikipedia would have answered your question.

Comment: ***Infinity Gauntlet: a six issue series*** will answer your question *(PS: there are a lot of differences from IW and Endgame both story-wise and character-wise)*

Comment: What I was interested in is knowing whether a time travel was used in the comics to undo Thanos actions, that's all.

Answer (score 11):

No. The MCU's plot's are inspired by the comics, but are not direct adaptations.

The closest to Infinity War/Endgame is the 1991 six-issue *The Infinity Gauntlet*. As [Wikipedia summarises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Infinity_Gauntlet):

> When Thanos uses his powers to kill half of the living beings in the universe, Adam Warlock leads Earth's remaining heroes against him. After the Infinity Gauntlet is stolen by Thanos' villainous granddaughter Nebula, Thanos aids the remaining heroes in defeating her. Warlock ultimately obtains the Infinity Gauntlet and uses its power to undo the death and destruction caused by Thanos.

So there's no time travel at all. The gauntlet is simply stolen a couple of times and then used.

Comment: Yeah, in the comics the reason for his genocide is just so a girl would like him. Lol

Comment: @Ben a girl that gets with everybody sooner or later